# Who borked the Area 51 stats?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

All beta sites (e.g. [Anime & Manga](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538/anime-manga)) are appearing with 0 Q/D and 0 avid users. [Site index](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is unaffected.

[image: LOL WAT (freehand red circles)]

In the Q&A spirit, my question is: Who borked the stats?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/

Comment: Son Goku :-) :-)

Comment: [Also reported on the Area 51 Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/area-51-stats-down)

Comment: Maybe they were... *puts on sunglasses* ...abducted by aliens.

Comment: @Gilles circular reference detected! ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was meeeeeeeeeeeee!

A reference change to the underlying libraries didn't expose itself as an issue until the library that relied on it was called.  As luck would have it, erroring requests in the multi-page fetcher were also swallowed (not intentionally). Silent fail FTW!

A fix has been deployed and stats should be updating properly now.

Fun fact: I don't have an Area 51 database locally. This fix brought to you by blind luck guesses and pushes to production for testing.

Comment: I knew it! The wheel never lies.

Answer (score 17):

In the meantime, the figures on the site's home page look correct. The [Stack Exchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) also has a correct-looking figure for questions per day.

I wouldn't be sad to see those Area 51 figures go away altogether. If they're going to stay, please at least correct the goals. As it is now, each beta invariably has people who compulsively compare the current figures against the goals and obsess about them, instead of looking at the big picture.

- The “questions per day” figure isn't very useful and many sites graduate without having reached the 15/day goal. How many posts are necessary to sustain a core community is highly variable; sites have survived for years with 1 q/day.
- Percentage answered is kind of useful, but mostly in its evolution on a given site. The figures are very dependent on the topic; for example language sites hover typically around 99% (for pretty much every question, there's a native who has something to say about it) while at the other end of the spectrum sites that involve software products have questions that are only answerable by the very few people who use exactly that same software function.
- Avid users isn't useful in its present form. *Active* users at certain reputation milestones would be useful as a graduation requirement — but even that shouldn't be displayed publicly as it pushes towards focusing on the metrics instead of focusing on quality (good answers, easy-to-find questions, welcoming ambience).
- Answer ratio isn't nearly as useful as quality checks on the answers. Community evaluations are much better for this.
- Visits per day is a measure of how the rest of the world finds the site useful… it's kind of nice to see that grow, but utterly useless as an absolute metric, and not that important: if you build it well, they will come.

Comment: Yes! It look over a year to convince people on my beta sites to stop looking at questions per day as a metric. These should be removed. Visits are really the only metric that I pay any attention to, since it's harder to game them.

Comment: And visits for various sites [were drastically changed recently](http://goo.gl/tSnc7l) when Google adjusted their algorithm. I do get that V/D can determine income  from ad revenue, but I feel like it's less important than it appears to be.

Comment: @Eric Participants don't care about ad revenue anyway, that's a matter for SE Inc. And they haven't turned on ads for any SE 2.0 site yet, not even Gaming.

Comment: @Gilles My point is that ad revenue is probably a metric that is important to SE, so they would evaluate V/D if it was directly correlated. Thus, the users of a site would be interested in V/D as it could be an indicator of closeness to graduation.

Comment: @Eric IIRC, revenue of beta sites is negligible compared to SOFU and hence not a real concern. (Can't speak for SE, obviously.)